# Access code of Java applet

Tags: java, applet

I'm used to inspecting JavaScript, HTML and CSS from the Chrome console. This time I want to inspect the source code of a Java applet. The line of code in question looks like:

```
<applet codebase="java/" code="Training.class" width="230" height="80"></applet>
```

How can I understand what this Java applet does from the Chrome console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. At least not without some effort. A Java applet is compiled code. So to inspect it, you'd need access to the source code. You can decompile it, or even inspect the actual byte code, but it'll be a lot harder than inspecting regular Javascript/html/css.

Comment: I've been working on a [Java decompiler](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/com.strobel/wiki/Java%20Decompiler) that also doubles as a disassembler.  Unlike javap, it includes color-coded output if you have an ANSI/xterm-256 compliant terminal.

Comment: Inspecting decompiled source or even Java bytecode isn't much harder then javascript. If the Javascript is minified, it's probably even easier.

Comment: It can be, but it all depends.